# How to order the word-match via bash script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep, kernel

the command `ads2 cls create` produces the following output:

```
cluster established ...
    nodes {
        node {
            name = "fdt-c-agx-0002";
            address = "http://172.16.11.89:9011/";
            state = "3";
        }
        node {
            name = "FDT-C-VM-0094";
            address = "http://172.16.11.49:9011/";
            state = "3";
        }
    }
```

What i'm trying to to is to find the `name` of each node and its status, assign each to a variable and print them so that the output looks like:

NODE-1 `name` has a state `state` #This conforms to the first node

NODE-2 `name` has a state `state` #This conforms to the second node

So I started with grep like `status-nod1="$(ads2 cls create | grep state | cut -d '"' -f 2)"` & `name-nod1="$(ads2 cls create | grep name | cut -d '"' -f 2)"`.

This works, however  finds all matches with `state` and 'name' and thus returns

```
3
3
fdt-c-agx-0002
FDT-C-VM-0094
```

So How can i output the match in the write order so that each node matches its state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grep for both state and name, you'll get the details in order

```
ads2 cls create | grep '\(state\|name\) =' | cut -d '"' -f 2 \
| while read name status ; do ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is really smart execpt how i'm I gonna print them as variable, because i want to check if the state equals to 3 which indicates a successful working node. Then i mus print the node name with its status

Comment: I mean i want to check if the status of each node is 3 which indicates a successully running node and if only the status of both nodes are 3, then each node is printed with its status

Comment: What do you mean by "print them as variable"? What happens when you replace `...` in my code with `echo $name $status`?

Comment: i mean like this `nameState="$(ads2 cls create | grep '\(state\|name\) =' | cut -d '"' -f 2)"`. Now the `nameState` variable contains all names and states and i want to check if state equals to 3 and then print the result acordingly. That why i need to save them in a variable